# How to perform AND in parsequery

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

The below is my code which tries to query based on 3 parameters. But the below query works for the OR logical function. Does anyone have any clue how do the AND logical function. I tried listing them normally as stated in the documentation but it always returns an empty List.

```
public class ResterauntList1 extends Activity {
    String rValue, cValue, lValue;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resteraunt_list1);
        rValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("restrauntName");
        cValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("restrauntCuisine");
        lValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("restrauntLocation");
        populateList(rValue, cValue, lValue);
    }

    private void populateList(final String rValue, final String cValue,
            final String lValue) {

        ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject> factory = new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
            public ParseQuery create() {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery("resdb");
        query.whereEqualTo("name", rValue);
        query.whereEqualTo("cuisine", cValue);
        query.whereEqualTo("area", lValue);
                return query;
            }
        };
        ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(
                this, factory);
        adapter.setTextKey("name");
        adapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new OnQueryLoadListener<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ResterauntList1.this);
                mProgressDialog
                        .setTitle("Searching for Restaurants matching your search");
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoaded(List<ParseObject> objects, Exception e) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.restListView1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                ParseObject object = (ParseObject) listView
                        .getItemAtPosition(position);
                String Id = object.getObjectId();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleRestraunt.class);
                i.putExtra("restId", Id);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }
```

Doesnt return any error but it always returns an empty listview. Any suggestions? Just as an extra the OR type query does work.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simple fix.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery("resdb");
           query.whereEqualTo("name", rValue);
           query.whereEqualTo("cuisine", cValue);
           query.whereEqualTo("area", lValue);
```

This will give you AND functionality.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No man i already tried this,that is the problem it doesnt work it returns an empty list.

Comment: Then your data is the issue, as that is the correct way to do an AND query.

Comment: I have to agree with @TimothyWalters then. Sorry I can't be of more assistance.